# I don't understand the solution of this exercise

Tags: java, loops

I am doing an exercise on Practiceit.edu and I have some trouble. The exercise is writing of the following codes:

```
int total = 25;
for (int number = 1; number <= (total / 2); number++ ) {
    total = total - number;
    System.out.println(total + " " + number );
}
```

My output is

```
24 1
22 2
19 3
15 4
10 5
4 6
-3 7
-11 8
-20 9
-30 10
-41 11
-53 12
```

because i think that number starts at 1 and finish at 12 (number <= (total / 2)). However, the result is

```
24 1
22 2
19 3
15 4
10 5
```

I don't understand this result, so can you help me explain it?

Comment: You do see the line of code that changes `total` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition used in the for loop says the `number` is less than or equal to (half of) `total`

```
number <= (total / 2)
```

The last line where that is true is 10 5

Everything after that doesn’t satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are changing the value of `total` which will be re-evaluated every-time in your loop

try

```
int total = 25;
int total2 = total;
for (int number = 1; number <= (total / 2); number++ ) {
    total2 = total2 - number;
    System.out.println(total2 + " " + number );
}
```

**output**

```
24 1
22 2
19 3
15 4
10 5
4 6
-3 7
-11 8
-20 9
-30 10
-41 11
-53 12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your total is reducing more and more each time you iterate.

```
total = total - number;
```

I.e.:

```
//1st iteration
25 - 1 = 24; // outputs 24 1

// 2nd iteration
24 - 2 = 22 // outputs 22 2

// 3rd iteration
22 - 3 = 19 // outputs 19 3

// 4th iteration
19 - 4 = 15 // outputs 15 4

// 5th iteration
15 - 5 = 10 // outputs 10 5
```

Etc.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

During the final iteration that is printed, total is 10 and number is 5. Once the for loop continues, number increases by 1 and total decreases to 4. The comparison is made between total = 4 / 2 = 2 and number = 6. This result is not printed since the comparison is already made. Thus, you exit the for loop.